# How to migrate from ga.js to gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Need to migrate from old school ga.js to newest gtag.js. How to do this? I've searched in help center, but only ga.js>analytics.js is found. Thanks.

Roman

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, simply replace code with new one. All data remains safe.